# How to prevent *.exe from installing into all my pyvenv3.5 venv (and what describes their purpose)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-packaging, python-venv

An initial `pyvenv3.5` venv at create time is about 9.5MB on disk, before adding any custom content.
Over 9% (!) of the venv disk-overhead are *.exe files, but all lack execute permission mode. One example: `lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/gui-32.exe`.

The linux `file` command says they are: `executable for MS Windows`. It looks like an obscure OS I'm certain my many pyvenv will never run on, and on which I'm unable to test.

What are the repercussions if I just delete them?
In initial tests my applications still work, a few of which are tkinter-based GUI.

Can I configure pyvenv somehow **not** to install them? Are they evidence I'm doing something wrong? The simple command I use to make an initial venv (causing the unwanted *.exe to install):

```
pyvenv-3.5 /some/path/myenv
```

Thanks.

edit: on centos 6.6, using `pip 9.0.1`
edit2: Where in the python-package docs are platform dependent *.exe members defined?

Comment: Can you please clarify what operating system you're using?