# What can I safely remove in a python lib folder?

Tags: python, pip, requirements, pyc

I am using:

```
mkdir -p build/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages
pipenv run pip install -r requirements.txt --target build/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages
```

to create a directory `build` with everything I need for my python project but I also need to save as much space as possible.

What can I safely remove in order to save space?

Maybe can I do `find build -type d -iname "*.dist-info" -exec rm -R {} \;` ?

Can I remove `*.py` if I leave `*.pyc`?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you try it out? When you want to delete a file, you can rename it (`abc.py` to `abc.py.del` for example). when everything still works you can remove the file. But you have to test *everything* to be sure...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps platform specific *.exe files, if your project doesn't need to run on Windows:

[How to prevent *.exe ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47066676/5156207)

Delete *.pyc (byte-compiled files), with an impact to load-time: 100% supported, unlike your trick of the reverse: retain just *.pyc (and delete most *.py sources) in some python versions; not safe IMHO but never tried it.

Comment: awesome thank you! i installed 3.9.7 alongside existing python:3.11.6-slim image and this reduced my image size by over 100MB